# How to find ISSN number of IEEE Sponsored (or IEEE related) Events?

Tags: publications, ieee

My University of Technology requires me to limit my research paper publications to certain venues, which have an associated ISSN number.  How do I find out the ISSN numbers for IEEE Sponsored events, such as in Croatia (Europe), when I can't find an ISSN number on their Web pages?  Here is the IEEE related conference URL: http://iwcmc.org/2015/?  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this list https://www.ieee.org/documents/2005_present_list_of_titles.xls from IEEE of upcoming events, and events from 2005 to present with all corresponding publication numbers.

As a comment points out, many of the listings do not have ISSN numbers. However, you can look at line 10935 of the excel sheet and see your conference.

IWCMC.  The IEEE conference number is 34432 and ISBN 978-1-4799-5345-5

Comment: Note that most of these IEEE conference proceedings don't have an ISSN.  In my experience, journals are assigned ISSN's, but conference proceedings volumes typically have an ISBN and no ISSN.  As conference proceedings volumes go the IEEE proceedings are generally considered to be pretty good, but not nearly at the same level as the IEEE Transactions On <whatever> journals.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Your right that the document does not have many ISSN numbers, but not sure that it is true for all conferences.  As of prestige, that would depend on which conference and journal, and what your criteria is.  H-Index by googles shows many fields where conferences are ranked higher than journals.

Comment: @BrianBorchers for example ICCAS http://2014.iccas.org/ posts their ISSN number, and the conference appears in IEEE, but the list does not include an ISSN number.