# Does IEEE provide an ISSN or ISBN list for searching on a specific journal?

Tags: publications, journals, ieee

Does IEEE provide an ISSN or ISBN list for searching a specific journal?

There is this [link](https://www.ieee.org/content/ieee-org/en/error/404.html/) from [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34704/how-to-find-issn-number-of-ieee-sponsored-or-ieee-related-events) but it is not active anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IEEE has organised it here: [IEEE Xplore Title Lists](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplorehelp/administrators-and-librarians/title-lists)

This list now contains information of all periodicals, conference publications, books, and standards in the IEEE Xplore database.

Comment: yes, that's it! Thanks!